# "H" letter is not sending to telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

the weirdest problem ever
I'm trying to create a Telegram bot on php.

When I'm trying to send to telegram bot ' H' (with space before H letter, uppercase) it's not working! Message is not received.

```
$text = ' H';
file_get_contents($website."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".$text);
```

End when it's only 'H' (without space). It works.

What's happening?

Comment: Try urlencode()... http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your text in the url:

```
file_get_contents($website."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=".urlencode($text));
```

[Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, for stupid question, but why is it happening only with H letter?

Comment: Its not happening because of `H` letter, but because of space ` ` before that letter. Space will be encoded to `%20`.

Comment: I see. The strange thing is when I change an H letter to any other, it works) Thanks anyway!

Comment: And there is no space before it? Or any other special character somewhere in `$text`?

Comment: ' R' sends ok, ' H' nope